# Cannot install typescript 1.4 after Windows 10 reservation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

I'm using VS2013 with typescript 1.0.
My team all works with typescript 1.4, so I decided to upgrade to 1.4, too.
My attempt failed with:

[image]

I suppose this happens because I was accepted Windows 10 offer reservation:
[image]

Should I have to cancel reservation or is there any other solution?
Currently I'm using Windows 8.1 and all required (without optional) windows updates are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing all optional updated through windows update